# Holomorphic functions (continuity of partial derivatives)

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic function i.e. for any $z_0\in \Omega$ there exists the limit:
$$f^{'}(z_0) = \lim_{z\mapsto z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}.$$ 
Let us write $f(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. I know how to prove that the partial derivatives exists of $u,v$ exist in any point $(x_0,y_0)\in\Omega$ and that they satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

How can one conclude that $u,v\in C^1(\Omega)$?

I would like to prove the Cauchy integral theorem using Green theorem. In order to do that I need $u,v\in C^1(\Omega)$.

Comment: Yes, holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable.  Even more than that, they are ... "analytic" ...  Seriously, to give a more complete answer, we would need to know the definition of "holomorphic" you want to use.

Comment: I added the definition.

Comment: This should be in any complex analysis text.  But probably the proof waits until after discussion of complex integrals.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to prove $u,v\in C^1(\Omega)$ without using integral. I edited the question.

Comment: I believe this was an open problem for many years: Without using integral, show for a function $f \, : \, \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ that if $f$ is (complex) differentiable, then the resulting derivative $f'$ is also differentiable.  After many years such a non-integral proof was done. But they are still much more difficult than the proofs using integral.

Comment: Isn't this question in EVERY complex analysis textbook?

Comment: See https://folk.ntnu.no/hanche/art/goursat/monthly648-652-a.pdf